# Provide a Subscribe Link for Newsletter Previews

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, newsletter

Newsletters are a great way to get non-community members to become actual members. But for some reason we have to instruct them on how to go to [stackexchange.com/newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/), search for *Raspberry Pi*, and click on the *subscribe* button. Wouldn't it be better, and possibly increase conversion rates, if we provided a subscribe link from the preview page? That way users can see some of the samplings of what we have to offer before deciding to subscribe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature already exists! Though it's completely undiscoverable at the moment..

Here is a page which you can use to promote your newsletter:

https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/promote?site=raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

**EDIT**

The main newsletter preview page (e.g. [here is Stack Overflow's](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=stackoverflow.com)) has a "Subscribe" button at the top now.

Comment: You mean that hover thing at the top wasn't there yesterday?

Comment: @random This appears to be a different URL. Thanks Emmett for the tip!